# update rows with same column value mysql and delete one

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

TABLE cartitems

CartItemId|CartId|sku_id|prod_id|quantity
1                1              2               1                 1
2                1              2               1                 1

I want to merger the rows having same sku_id and update the quantity and delete one duplicate row like this

CartItemId|CartId|sku_id|prod_id|quantity
1                1              2               1                 2

if delete doesnt happens its okay. i l manage it later.

Answer (score 0):

> it's simple [Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx) function with an [ORDER BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) Keyword to
>   use.

try,

```
select 
    min(CartItemId),
    min(CartId),
    sku_id,
    Sum(quantity) from cartitems group by sku_id
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.This is selecting the data. I wnat the quantity to be updated. and delete one duplicate row.